# How to access the photos in a private group via the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm new to the Facebook Graph API. I've figured out how to access the feed of a secret group, but the posts with photos uploaded to them don't show the photos. I requested every permission to make sure it wasn't an OAuth issue. The post shows up with a type of `status`. I tried connecting it to `photos` and I always get an empty `data` array.

I looked at a public group, and the posts with photos show up as a type `photo` and contain a picture element.

If I post the picture in the secret group, then I can access it shows up as a photo post. If I update the picture in the exact same way as another user, then it shows up as 'status' with no picture. This smells like a bug (since I've requested full permissions for both user and friends).

I'm currently using the web based [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and I tried the beta version too, just to be sure.

If there is a different API I need to use to access secret group photos, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug. I've already reported it (on November 28 '13) but yet to be resolved.

I'm not able to change the bug's privacy settings so the bug is visible to me only.

I'll post here after its resolved.

Comment: Thanks, it seemed like a bug to me.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that too.